# Simple ASP.NET Razor page on local IIS 8.5 - 500.19 0x8007000d error

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor

I've built sample Razor webpage that works perfectly fine and I decided to deploy it on local IIS enabled on Windows 8.1. (IIS 8.5).

I used the publish feature through the file system that copied relevant files to Inetpub subfolder.

When I try to access the webpage I get this error:

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Error Code: 0x8007000d
Config Error:
Config File: (correct path)
```

The webconfig is suspiciously short but given simplicity of the page - perhaps long enough?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I made pretty thorough search of similar issues here and other google-returned materials and overall nothing helped.
I'm pretty sure all relevant components that I could install for IIS I have installed already.
All configuration files are correctly formed.
The security is fine - I can play with webconfig content and get different error a bit which indicate IIS can access the config file.

The only thing that surprises me is that sometimes when I access various config icons on IIS for the page I get error like this:

i.e. for .NET Profile:
There was error while performing this operation.
Details: (nothing written here)
Filename: \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mypagefolder\web.config
Error: (nothing written here)

Is my web.config missing some sections?

EDIT: I also dropped the published application on some other IIS server that is used for other applications and the result is the same which make me inclined to believe s.t. is either wrong with the application publish process or s.t. is very weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your web.config, it is found that you are trying to deploying ASP.NET Core website. It requires

1. .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed on the hosting server
2. Application Pool .NET CLR version set to "No Managed Code"
3. Ensure that the Application Pool Identity user has read permissions on the published folder.

For details check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.0

First thing I suggest is to check is the .NET CLR version of your application pool and also check the AppPool Identity has read permissions on the published folder

Comment: I've installed .NET Core Runtime 2.0.7, made sure that both DefaultAppPool and my dedicated AppPool have full control over the folder with the app and both of them are set to "No Managed Code" - the result is the same.

Comment: Do you have .NET Core Hosting Bundle installed on the server? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.0.7
Check the hosting bundle installer link

Comment: My target IIS is on my PC

Comment: Yep even then you need that hosting bundle because for hosting ASP.NET Core app requires that hosting bundle

Comment: As I said in the first comment I have .Net core runtime installed in version 2.0.7. if I need something else to have the bundle installed them I'm missing it

Comment: @nimdil install the hosting bundle from here and then try
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.0.7-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Comment: I will check again but it looks like exact same thing I have installed already

Comment: @nimdil also check for any exception in windows event logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Windows 2012 Server. Although I had the SDK 2.1 installed, it only worked when I installed Runtime & Hosting Bundle.
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

It's important to mention that, in order to see this option, I had to click on "Can't find the file you want? Find more in .NET Core 2.1 downloads.".

By default this page is not shown.